# Validation is not working proper when placeholder string and text entered is same

Tags: jquery, validation

> **Using:** Jquery and jquery validate js
>
> **Error:** If the textbox value and plceholder string is same then the required field validation is firing,

Code:

---

```
<form method="post" action="#">
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your">
    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="you@example.com">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

.

```
// Test if the submitted value is  equal to our placeholder.
$.validator.addMethod('notPlaceholder', function(val, el) {
    return ( val !== $(el).attr('placeholder') );
}, $.validator.messages.required);

$('form').validate({
    rules: {
        name: {
            required: true,
            notPlaceholder: true
        },
        email: {
            required: true,
            notPlaceholder: true,
            email: true
        }
    },
    
    // This is just for jsfiddle.
    debug: true,
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        $.each( $(form).serializeArray(), function(i, f) {
            $(form).append('<p>' +f.value+ '</p>');
        });
    }
});
```

---

> **Required:** form  should post

<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cmZ5U/4/)</kbd>

can anyone help me out?

Comment: Why notplaceholder required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove `notPlaceholder: true` like in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cmZ5U/1/)

```
//rest of your code here
rules: {
    name: {
        required: true,
        //notPlaceholder: true // <- REMOVE ME
    },
    email: {
        required: true,
        //notPlaceholder: true // <- REMOVE ME
        email: true
    }
},
//rest of your code here
```

Comment: where should i remove

Comment: @TonyStark, what exactly do you want? Do you want the value and placeholder to be same or not?

Answer (score 1):

```
$('form').validate({
    rules: {
        name: {
            required: true,

        },
        email: {
            required: true,

            email: true
        }
    },

    // This is just for jsfiddle.
    debug: true,
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        $.each( $(form).serializeArray(), function(i, f) {
            $(form).append('<p>' +f.value+ '</p>');
        });
    }
});
```

Your jquery should looks like

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cmZ5U/)

Answer (score 0):

**Try this code :**

```
$.validator.addMethod('notPlaceholder', function(val, el) {
    return ( val !== $(el).attr('placeholder') );
}, $.validator.messages.required);

$('form').validate({
    rules: {
        name: {
            required: true,

        },
        email: {
            required: true,

            email: true
        }
    },

    // This is just for jsfiddle.
    debug: true,
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        $.each( $(form).serializeArray(), function(i, f) {
            $(form).append('<p>' +f.value+ '</p>');
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what exactly you are doing, but you can do this:

```
$.validator.addMethod('notPlaceholder', function(val, el) {
    return !(val !== $(el).attr('placeholder'));
}
```

That should work.

And for submitting the form, you can do:

```
$(form)[0].submit();
```